# Seaborn Correlation Coefficient on PairGrid

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a matplotlib or seaborn plot I could use with g.map_lower or g.map_upper to get the correlation coefficient displayed for each bivariate plot like shown below? plt.text was manually mapped to get the below example which is a tedious process.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show correlation values in pairplot using seaborn in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832204/show-correlation-values-in-pairplot-using-seaborn-in-python)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can pass any function to the `map_*` methods as long as it follows a few rules: 1) it should plot onto the "current" axes, 2) it should take two vectors as positional arguments, and 3) it should accept a `color` keyword argument (optionally using it, if you want to be compatible with the `hue` option).

So in your case you just need to define a little `corrfunc` function and then map it across the axes you want to have annotated:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white")

mean = np.zeros(3)
cov = np.random.uniform(.2, .4, (3, 3))
cov += cov.T
cov[np.diag_indices(3)] = 1
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
                xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, palette=["red"])
g.map_upper(plt.scatter, s=10)
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False)
g.map_lower(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues_d")
g.map_lower(corrfunc)
```

[image]

Comment: What does this contour diagram represent?

Comment: Perfect. You may want to update distplot to histplot since distplot is deprecated.