# Seaborn Pairplot Pearsons P statistic

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I've been working through an assignment of data analysis as a novice at python/seaborn/scipy.stats/matplotlib.pyplot etc

[Seaborn Correlation Coefficient on PairGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942577/seaborn-correlation-coefficient-on-pairgrid)
 this link which has helped me to present a relationship between my variables via a pearsons R score.
However since the output of the Pearsons test also should have a p value in order to indicate statistical significance I am looking at a way to add the P value to the annotation on my plot.

```
g = sns.pairplot(unoutlieddata, vars=['bia', 'DW', 'HW', 'jackson', 'girths'], kind="reg")

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, _ = sps.pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f}".format(r),
                xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

g.map(corrfunc)
sns.plt.show()
```

Shown is my code in the format of the link provided. 
sps=scipy.stats. unoutlied data is a dataframe which has been filtered to  remove outliers

Any ideas would be Fantastic

Regards

Comment: Thanks to the guys editing this question so it makes sense as well: sorry it was originally rough formatting: my first question, and as I say I'm a novice

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if anyone will ever see this but after speaking to someone who knows a bit more the answer was as follows

## Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    (r, p) = pearsonr(x, y)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate("r = {:.2f} ".format(r),
                xy=(.1, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)
    ax.annotate("p = {:.3f}".format(p),
                xy=(.4, .9), xycoords=ax.transAxes)

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
df = df[df["species"] == "setosa"]
graph = sns.pairplot(df)
graph.map(corrfunc)
plt.show()
```

## Result

[image: seaborn pairplot]

Comment: It'd be helful if you attach the output plot for illustration.