# Displaying regression output in Seaborn pairgrid

Tags: pandas, regression, curve-fitting, seaborn, significance

I'm a fan of the pairgrid regplots Seaborn outputs, like below:

[image: plots]

My issue is, I can't see the R and P values for these regression models.

Does Seaborn have a way to output the stats values on the regplot when it's part of a grid?

My code:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df8,
                 y_vars=["Candidate_x"],
                 x_vars=["mobile_homes", "white_labor_participation",
                         "Unemployment_x", "less_hs_diploma",
                         "difference_x"], size=3)
g.map(sns.regplot, color=".3")
g.set(ylim=(0, 1), yticks=[0, 5, 10]);
```

Comment: Have you looked at jointplot ? seems pairgrid does not have option for pearsonr and p to be in plot ...

Comment: @sb0709 Can it do the multiples? Needs to work with my hadoop cluster.

Comment: only this way as listed in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/35044845/2027457

Comment: Will take a crack at it later. Shame Seaborn doesn't offer this for Hadoop users.

Comment: Does this post answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942577/seaborn-correlation-coefficient-on-pairgrid