# Seaborn plotting a correlation plot fails due to non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing being deprecated

Tags: seaborn, python-3.7

I recently started running the newest version of anaconda (2018.12 with py37_0) and I am using jupyter notebooks to run my code. Prior to installing this version I was using Python 3.2.2 and the code presented below would run smoothly. The code uses Seaborn to produce a correlation plot using variables taken from a pandas dataframe. However, now I get "IndexError: tuple index out of range" and I don't know how to fix that error.

A similar problem has been reported previously:

[FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52110869/futurewarning-using-a-non-tuple-sequence-for-multidimensional-indexing-is-depre)

[FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated use `arr[tuple(seq)]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594235/futurewarning-using-a-non-tuple-sequence-for-multidimensional-indexing-is-depre)

Neither of this solutions seems to work for me.

Lastly, the code to plot the correlation for the variables in my data frame comes from:

[Correlation matrix plot with coefficients on one side, scatterplots on another, and distributions on diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139899/correlation-matrix-plot-with-coefficients-on-one-side-scatterplots-on-another)

The data to create a pandas dataframe was taken from a csv file of a Kaggle competition:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/

I used the "winequality-white.csv" file

```py
import pandas as np
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv')

def corrdot(*args, **kwargs):
    corr_r = args[0].corr(args[1], 'pearson')
    corr_text = f"{corr_r:2.2f}".replace("0.", ".")
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_axis_off()
    marker_size = abs(corr_r) * 10000
    ax.scatter(.5, .5, marker_size, corr_r, alpha=0.6, cmap="coolwarm",
               vmin=-1, vmax=1, transform=ax.transAxes)
    font_size = abs(corr_r) * 40 + 5
    ax.annotate(corr_text, [.5, .5,],  xycoords="axes fraction",
                ha='center', va='center', fontsize=font_size)

sns.set(style='white', font_scale=1.6)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, aspect=1.4, diag_sharey=False)
g.map_lower(sns.regplot, lowess=True, ci=False, line_kws={'color': 'black'})
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde_kws={'color': 'black'})
g.map_upper(corrdot)
```

Expected results can be found as the answer for:

[Correlation matrix plot with coefficients on one side, scatterplots on another, and distributions on diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139899/correlation-matrix-plot-with-coefficients-on-one-side-scatterplots-on-another)

Actual results:

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:1713: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  return np.add.reduce(sorted[indexer] * weights, axis=axis) / sumval

Traceback:

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-68b4a938aa72> in <module>
     17 g.map_lower(sns.regplot, lowess=True, ci=False, line_kws={'color': 'black'})
     18 g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde_kws={'color': 'black'})
---> 19 g.map_upper(corrdot)

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py in map_upper(self, func, **kwargs)
   1488                 color = self.palette[k] if kw_color is None else kw_color
   1489                 func(data_k[x_var], data_k[y_var], label=label_k,
-> 1490                      color=color, **kwargs)
   1491 
   1492             self._clean_axis(ax)

<ipython-input-8-68b4a938aa72> in corrdot(*args, **kwargs)
      7     marker_size = abs(corr_r) * 10000
      8     ax.scatter(.5, .5, marker_size, corr_r, alpha=0.6, cmap="coolwarm",
----> 9                vmin=-1, vmax=1, transform=ax.transAxes)
     10     font_size = abs(corr_r) * 40 + 5
     11     ax.annotate(corr_text, [.5, .5,],  xycoords="axes fraction",

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4209             try:  # First, does 'c' look suitable for value-mapping?
   4210                 c_array = np.asanyarray(c, dtype=float)
-> 4211                 n_elem = c_array.shape[0]
   4212                 if c_array.shape in xy_shape:
   4213                     c = np.ma.ravel(c_array)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You're mixing up two things here. One is a warning, which you currently cannot avoid, but which is harmless. The other is an Error which should not occur and is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments to scatter should be lists or arrays. Hence `plt.scatter(1,1, c=1, vmin=0, vmax=2)` does not work, but

```
plt.scatter([1],[1], c=[1], vmin=0, vmax=2)
```

will work.

Comment: changing the def corrdot (*args, **kwargs) 7th line to ax.scatter
```python
([.5], [.5], marker_size, corr_r, alpha=0.6, cmap="coolwarm",
               vmin=-1, vmax=1, transform=ax.transAxes) 
```
raises the following error: IndexError: tuple index out of range. The comment after the script is: 

C:\Users\Public\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:1713: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, whic...

Comment: No you need to change it to `ax.scatter([.5], [.5], marker_size, [corr_r], alpha=0.6, ...)` I have updated the original answer in the meantime.