# How to plot correlation matrix with python? Like in R library(PerformanceAnalytics)

Tags: python, r, data-visualization, data-analysis

I'm trying to plot a correlation matrix.[image: Like this one]
On the one side, there should be a graph scatter plot, on the other side the correlation value of two crossed values.

All I know is the pair grid from seaborn. But it doesn't show the correlation value, it has only scatter plot.[image]

Maybe somebody knows Python equivalent of the R ?

```
    library(PerformanceAnalytics)
    chart.Correlation(mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no type of graph that I want.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139899/correlation-matrix-plot-with-coefficients-on-one-side-scatterplots-on-another) should answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, you can easily use df.corr() :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # Your data 
corr = df.corr() # Calculates correlation matrix
```

If you are using **jupyter**:

```
corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm') # This line plots nicely visualized matrix of correlation
```

Or using **matplotlib**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(corr)
```