# Seaborn pairplot with correlation heatmap at the same time

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, heatmap, scatter-plot

I'm trying to have on the same figure the seaborn pairplot (scatter upper half, kde diagonal) and a correlation heatmap (coloured squares lower half).
I have currently both of them usable, but I can't manage to join/merge them.
I have already tried with the Pairgrid function, but I was unsuccessful.

here is my code in my notebook for both of them:

```
#Heatmap lower half
corr = df.iloc[:,-3:].corr("pearson")
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3, center=0,
            square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5},annot = True)

#Pairplot the rest
g = sns.pairplot(df.iloc[:,-3:],hue="target")
```

[image]

So I just want the empty upper half to be filled with the rest of the pairplot. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: What you can do instead is this:
[Correlation matrix plot with coefficients on one side, scatterplots on another, and distributions on diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139899/correlation-matrix-plot-with-coefficients-on-one-side-scatterplots-on-another). It is not exactly the same but it is quite close to what you wanted.